# How to create session in my app with httpget android?

Tags: android

I am developing an app, in this i create login of user but i want to use session using sharedpreferences inside this login. How do i implement session in this?
Following is my code please suggest me, how do i do inside my code?

public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
    private EditText usernameEditText;
    private EditText passwordEditText;
    private Button sendGetReqButton;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        usernameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
        passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

        sendGetReqButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        sendGetReqButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v.getId() == R.id.button){

            // Get the values given in EditText fields
            String userID = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
            String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
            System.out.println("Givennames is :" + userID + " Given password is :" + password);

            // Pass those values to connectWithHttpGet() method
            connectWithHttpGet(userID, password);

            Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    }

    private void connectWithHttpGet(String userID, String password) {

        // Connect with a server is a time consuming process.
        //Therefore we use AsyncTask to handle it
        // From the three generic types;
        //First type relate with the argument send in execute()
        //Second type relate with onProgressUpdate method which I haven't use in this code
        //Third type relate with the return type of the doInBackground method, which also the input type of the onPostExecute method
        class HttpGetAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                // As you can see, doInBackground has taken an Array of Strings as the argument
                //We need to specifically get the givenUsername and givenPassword

                String paramUsername = params[0];
                String paramPassword = params[1];
                System.out.println("userID" + paramUsername + " password is :" + paramPassword);

                // Create an intermediate to connect with the Internet
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                // Sending a GET request to the web page that we want
                // Because of we are sending a GET request, we have to pass the values through the URL
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com/ypAndroid/api/doLogin?userID=" + paramUsername + "&password=" + paramPassword);

                try {
                    // execute(); executes a request using the default context.
                    // Then we assign the execution result to HttpResponse
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                    System.out.println("httpResponse// getEntity() ; obtains the message entity of this response");
                    // getContent() ; creates a new InputStream object of the entity.
                    // Now we need a readable source to read the byte stream that comes as the httpResponse
                    InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

                    // We have a byte stream. Next step is to convert it to a Character stream
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

                    // Then we have to wraps the existing reader (InputStreamReader) and buffer the input
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

                    // InputStreamReader contains a buffer of bytes read from the source stream and converts these into characters as needed.
                    //The buffer size is 8K
                    //Therefore we need a mechanism to append the separately coming chunks in to one String element
                    // We have to use a class that can handle modifiable sequence of characters for use in creating String
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    String bufferedStrChunk = null;

                    // There may be so many buffered chunks. We have to go through each and every chunk of characters
                    //and assign a each chunk to bufferedStrChunk String variable
                    //and append that value one by one to the stringBuilder
                    while((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                        stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                    }

                    // Now we have the whole response as a String value.
                    //We return that value then the onPostExecute() can handle the content
                    System.out.println("Returninge of doInBackground :" + stringBuilder.toString());

                    // If the Username and Password match, it will return "working" as response
                    // If the Username or Password wrong, it will return "invalid" as response
                    return stringBuilder.toString();

                } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                    System.out.println("Exceptionrates caz of httpResponse :" + cpe);
                    cpe.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.out.println("Secondption generates caz of httpResponse :" + ioe);
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            // Argument comes for this method according to the return type of the doInBackground() and
            //it is the third generic type of the AsyncTask
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                System.out.println("Post result :" + result);

                if(!result.equals(null))
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HTTP GET is working...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else  if(result.equals("failure")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

        // Initialize the AsyncTask class
        HttpGetAsyncTask httpGetAsyncTask = new HttpGetAsyncTask();
        // Parameter we pass in the execute() method is relate to the first generic type of the AsyncTask
        // We are passing the connectWithHttpGet() method arguments to that
        httpGetAsyncTask.execute(userID, password);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create SharedPreferences key value for storing the logged user credentials in the onPostExecute method

```
SharedPreferences spref = getSharedPreferences("MySpref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spref.edit();

        editor.putString("User", usr);
             editor.commit();
```

Some modifications added in your code

```
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    usernameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
    passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

    sendGetReqButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    sendGetReqButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    // Regitration Button is required

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v.getId() == R.id.button){


        // Get the values given in EditText fields
        String userID = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
        String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
        System.out.println("Givennames is :" + userID + " Given password is :" + password);

        if (userID!=null && password!=null) {
            // Pass those values to connectWithHttpGet() method
            connectWithHttpGet(userID, password);
        }


       // Here Registration need to be in different button 
       // Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class);
      //            startActivity(in);


    }
}

private void connectWithHttpGet(String userID, String password) {

    // Here you can check newtork connection is ok or not


    HttpGetAsyncTask httpGetAsyncTask = new HttpGetAsyncTask();
    // Parameter we pass in the execute() method is relate to the first generic type of the AsyncTask
    // We are passing the connectWithHttpGet() method arguments to that
    httpGetAsyncTask.execute(userID, password);
}

    // Connect with a server is a time consuming process.
    //Therefore we use AsyncTask to handle it
    // From the three generic types;
    //First type relate with the argument send in execute()
    //Second type relate with onProgressUpdate method which I haven't use in this code
    //Third type relate with the return type of the doInBackground method, which also the input type of the onPostExecute method
    private class  HttpGetAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        String usr;

        protected void onPreExecute() {


        // Here you can use loading animation


        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // As you can see, doInBackground has taken an Array of Strings as the argument
            //We need to specifically get the givenUsername and givenPassword

            String paramUsername = params[0];
            usr=paramUsername;
            String paramPassword = params[1];
            System.out.println("userID" + paramUsername + " password is :" + paramPassword);

            // Create an intermediate to connect with the Internet
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // Sending a GET request to the web page that we want
            // Because of we are sending a GET request, we have to pass the values through the URL
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com/ypAndroid/api/doLogin?userID=" + paramUsername + "&password=" + paramPassword);

            try {
                // execute(); executes a request using the default context.
                // Then we assign the execution result to HttpResponse
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                System.out.println("httpResponse// getEntity() ; obtains the message entity of this response");
                // getContent() ; creates a new InputStream object of the entity.
                // Now we need a readable source to read the byte stream that comes as the httpResponse
                InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

                // We have a byte stream. Next step is to convert it to a Character stream
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

                // Then we have to wraps the existing reader (InputStreamReader) and buffer the input
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

                // InputStreamReader contains a buffer of bytes read from the source stream and converts these into characters as needed.
                //The buffer size is 8K
                //Therefore we need a mechanism to append the separately coming chunks in to one String element
                // We have to use a class that can handle modifiable sequence of characters for use in creating String
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String bufferedStrChunk = null;

                // There may be so many buffered chunks. We have to go through each and every chunk of characters
                //and assign a each chunk to bufferedStrChunk String variable
                //and append that value one by one to the stringBuilder
                while((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                }

                // Now we have the whole response as a String value.
                //We return that value then the onPostExecute() can handle the content
                System.out.println("Returninge of doInBackground :" + stringBuilder.toString());

                // If the Username and Password match, it will return "working" as response
                // If the Username or Password wrong, it will return "invalid" as response
                return stringBuilder.toString();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                System.out.println("Exceptionrates caz of httpResponse :" + cpe);
                cpe.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println("Secondption generates caz of httpResponse :" + ioe);
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        // Argument comes for this method according to the return type of the doInBackground() and
        //it is the third generic type of the AsyncTask
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            System.out.println("Post result :" + result);

            if(!result.equals(null))

                // Here you do the logic 
            // if the response is JSON then you have use json Parser
            //  JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);
         // if user is valid then you can store it in SharedPreferences 
        // response maybe different types so you have check it vaild or not


                SharedPreferences spref = getSharedPreferences("MySpref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spref.edit();

            editor.putString("User", usr);
                  editor.commit();

                 //YOU CAN NAVIGATE TO NEW PAGE

             //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HTTP GET is working...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else  if(result.equals("failure")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this changes works

Comment: @Rohu your code need more changes, some modifications are done, hope this will work